# How to fix an OpenCV AI Hands critical code error in Python?

Tags: python, mediapipe, cvzone

So I have been watching a video online and was trying to replicate the same project with the same code. It worked in the beginning but after I added another script to my VS Code project folder it completely broke and throws an error every time I run the program. I tried reinstalling and upgrading all of the packages I used but still the same error. Can anyone please suggest what may be the result of this error?

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time
 
class handDetector():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=2, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon
 
        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands,
                                        self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
 
    def findHands(self, img, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)
        # print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)
 
        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for handLms in self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                if draw:
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms,
                                               self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
        return img
 
    def findPosition(self, img, handNo=0, draw=True):
 
        lmList = []
        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            myHand = self.results.multi_hand_landmarks[handNo]
            for id, lm in enumerate(myHand.landmark):
                # print(id, lm)
                h, w, c = img.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
                # print(id, cx, cy)
                lmList.append([id, cx, cy])
                if draw:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 15, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
 
        return lmList
 
 
def main():
    pTime = 0
    cTime = 0
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    detector = handDetector()
    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        img = detector.findHands(img)
        lmList = detector.findPosition(img)
        if len(lmList) != 0:
            print(lmList[4])
        cTime = time.time()
        fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
        pTime = cTime
        cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (10, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,
                    (255, 0, 255), 3)
 
        cv2.imshow("Image", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Hand Gensture Tracking AI\HandTrackingModule.py", line 71, in <module>
    main()
  File "d:\Hand Gensture Tracking AI\HandTrackingModule.py", line 51, in main
    detector = handDetector()
  File "d:\Hand Gensture Tracking AI\HandTrackingModule.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solutions\hands.py", line 114, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 288, in __init__
    self._input_side_packets = {
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 289, in <dictcomp>
    name: self._make_packet(self._side_input_type_info[name], data)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 591, in _make_packet
    return getattr(packet_creator, 'create_' + packet_data_type.value)(data)
TypeError: create_int(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: int) -> mediapipe.python._framework_bindings.packet.Packet

Invoked with: 0.5
```

Comment: Please edit the text of the full stacktrace into your post. See [ask] for why this is a rule here.

Comment: It looks like `mp.solutions.hands` requires either `detectionCon` or `trackCon` to be an integer, not a float.

Comment: I think you are looking at an old sample.  `mp.solutions.hands.Hands` takes 5 parameters; the third parameter (complexity) is missing from your code.

Comment: that "video", it's Murtaza/cvzone, right?

Comment: How old is this video you are watching? Libraries change all the time, a video that's even a year or two old might be slightly out of date.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code lies in line 11-12:
`self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(self.mode, self.maxHands, self.detectionCon, self.trackCon)`
The class `Hands()` takes in 5 arguments, but it seems like you have missed the "complexity" parameter.

Your modified code:

```py
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import time
 
class handDetector():
    def __init__(self, mode=False, maxHands=2, complexity=1, detectionCon=0.5, trackCon=0.5):
        self.mode = mode
        self.maxHands = maxHands
        self.detectionCon = detectionCon
        self.trackCon = trackCon
 
        self.mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
        self.hands = self.mpHands.Hands(mode, maxHands, complexity, detectionCon, trackCon)
        self.mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
 
    def findHands(self, img, draw=True):
        imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        self.results = self.hands.process(imgRGB)
        # print(results.multi_hand_landmarks)
 
        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            for handLms in self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                if draw:
                    self.mpDraw.draw_landmarks(img, handLms,
                                               self.mpHands.HAND_CONNECTIONS)
        return img
 
    def findPosition(self, img, handNo=0, draw=True):
 
        lmList = []
        if self.results.multi_hand_landmarks:
            myHand = self.results.multi_hand_landmarks[handNo]
            for id, lm in enumerate(myHand.landmark):
                # print(id, lm)
                h, w, c = img.shape
                cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
                # print(id, cx, cy)
                lmList.append([id, cx, cy])
                if draw:
                    cv2.circle(img, (cx, cy), 15, (255, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
 
        return lmList
 
 
def main():
    pTime = 0
    cTime = 0
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    detector = handDetector()
    while True:
        success, img = cap.read()
        img = detector.findHands(img)
        lmList = detector.findPosition(img)
        if len(lmList) != 0:
            print(lmList[4])
        cTime = time.time()
        fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
        pTime = cTime
        cv2.putText(img, str(int(fps)), (10, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 3,
                    (255, 0, 255), 3)
 
        cv2.imshow("Image", img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If this still doesn't solve your problem, then take note of the following things:

- If you are using a virtual environment in vscode and try installing mediapipe or opencv-python, you may face a "numpy" version error. However, if you try running this code in PyCharm and installing these packages in the python interpreter, you won't face any errors.
- You must be using python 3.7.0 or below as mediapipe doesn't support the newer versions.

Another tip to keep things simpler would be to use the "pydetection" module. You will need to install these packages:

```
pip install mediapipe
pip install opencv-python
pip install pydetetcion
```

The pydetection module will simplify the code a lot!

```py
import pydetection as hand # The pydetection module
import cv2 # We will use this for reading and displaying webcam frames

detector = hand.HandRecogniser()
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # Change the number for a different camera. 0 is the default one.

while True:
    _, frame = webcam.read() # Gets a frame of the current webcam feed
  
    processed_image, hand_landmark_position = detector.findHands(frame, draw=True)
    
    cv2.imshow(processed_image) # Show the image with the hands outlined
    
    # Add a delay of 1 millisecond and check for the keystroke "q"
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord("q"):
      break
```

Github page to pydetection: https://github.com/Ayaan-Imran/pydetection